# Relationship between http 404 error and urls

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I'm a bit confused with when http 404 will occurs.

Using Spring petclinic as example.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/

Test and result

```
http://localhost:9966/petclinic/ -> load successfully

http://localhost:9966/petclinic/abdfef -> http 404

http://localhost:9966/ -> blank page
```

I clearly remember application will provide an 404 if I enter xxx://localhost:9966/

May I know what determines the 404 from happening ? and how do I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to pretend for this that your document root is /var/www

When you go to `http://localhost:9966/petclinic/abdfef`, your web server attempts to load `/var/www/petclinic/abdfef`, which doesn't exist.

When you go to `http://localhost:9966/`, it looks for `/var/www/`

It does exist, but it may not have an index or default file. Some web servers will display a 404 error, some will display a 403 error, and some will give you a list of all files in that directory. It depends on the web server as well as how you have the web server configured.

[For more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index)